# Unix Shell script task. Files as parameters?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I got this question. I am still a newbie, I don't know how to make files as parameters.

> There is an attendance list of a class (`class.dat` - name; neptun code). At the end of summer they keep a great party with guests too. The participants of the party are given in a file `party.txt` (name; neptun code). Create a script `together.sh` which contains the names from `class.dat` and from `party.dat` but each name only once! The parameters of the script should be the two file names.

Comment: Make your query or quest more clear!

Answer (score 4):

Command-line arguments to bash scripts are stored in the special variables `$1` for the first space-separated argument, `$2` for the second and so on.

See also [TLDP Advanced Bash Scripting Guide - 4.4. Special Variable Types](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) (section `Positional parameters`) or [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (section `Parameters`).

You should remember to always put your variables inside double-quotes (like `"$1"`) though, to avoid getting them split up if they contain spaces.

Here is an example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

echo "The first file, $1, starts with these lines:"
head "$1"

echo "The second file, $2, ends with these lines:"
tail "$2"
```

For getting all unique lines from both files together, take a look at the [`sort` command (type `man sort`)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort), especially its `-u` option...